# error in your SQL syntax ('not null' at setup)

Tags: php, mysql, null

I tried to set up a mysql database with PHP like this:

```
$create_table = "CREATE TABLE `anmeldungen` 
(
ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY(ID),
vorname TEXT DEFAULT NOT NULL,
name TEXT DEFAULT NOT NULL,
ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)";
```

But it just responds

`You have an error [...] near 'NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(ID), vorname TEXT DEFAULT NOT NULL, name TEXT DEFAULT NOT' at line 3`

I can't find the error, even without `DEFAULT` it doesn't work.
A while back this worked somehow, but maybe I have just looked too much at it :D

Hope you can help me as an nearly beginner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue because of `DEFAULT` have `NULL` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` option only. Please check below. `NOT NULL` is not in `DEFAULT` dropdown options

```
$create_table = "CREATE TABLE `anmeldungen` 
(
ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY(ID),
vorname TEXT NOT NULL,
name TEXT NOT NULL,
ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)"
```

Executed code in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

```
$create_table = "CREATE TABLE `anmeldungen` 
(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NOT NULL, 
    vorname TEXT DEFAULT NOT NULL,
    name TEXT DEFAULT NOT NULL,
    ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID) -- comes last after all columns definitions
)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your primary key declaration has to come after the column definitions.

```
$create_table = "CREATE TABLE `anmeldungen` 
(
    `ID`      INT       AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NOT NULL, 
    `vorname` TEXT      DEFAULT NOT NULL,
    `name`    TEXT      DEFAULT NOT NULL,
    `ts`      TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)";
```